# 'datetime' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

Below is the query I am trying on chinook DB but I am getting this error. Please help me with how can I solve this?
Error ==> 'datetime' is not a recognized built-in function name.

```sql
select count(i.invoiceid), sum(i.total)
from invoice as i
where i.invoicedate between datetime('2011-01-01 00:00:00') and datetime('2011-12-31 00:00:00'
```

Comment: What made you think `datetime()` *was* a function? You don't need that to make `datetime` literals, just use quotes `'2011-12-31...'` Note that this query will miss out the last day of 2011, you probably want `where i.invoicedate >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00' and i.invoicedate < '2012-01-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: datetime is not the function is datatype on sql server please use convert function then try. Ex:  Select CONVERT (Varchar, GETDATE() ,103)

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 Considering OP is trying to compare, not display, then converting is a bad idea. And you should always specify `varchar` length

Comment: Note that, for `datetime` and `smalldatetime` the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` is ambiguous.You're better off using `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`.

Comment: Since you seem to be learning tsql, now would be a good time to read the documentation about [cast and convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - the functions that change datatypes. But as already noted, you don't need to use these if your literals are in a valid (and safe!) format. I expect that invoicedate is actually a date column, not datetime.

Comment: `datetime()` is not in the list  [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#GetSystemDateandTimeValues)

Comment: @Charlieface datetimefromparts() is much safer than assuming you can use a string literal for datetime values. On non-US SQL Server instances, for example, `set dateformat dmy; declare @Example datetime = '2011-12-31 00:00:00.000';` errors with `Msg 242 Level 16 State 3 Line 1 The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, but `20111231 00:00:00.000` does work

Comment: Using a non-ambiguous format is more of a must, @AlwaysLearning , in my opinion and often far easier to read: `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` always work, regardless of data type and language settings.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server automatically converts strings in the "right" format to `datetime`s:

```
where i.invoicedate between '2011-01-01T00:00:00') and '2011-12-31T00:00:00'
```

This is [explained](http://%20%20%20%20where%20i.invoicedate%20between%20%272011-01-01%27%20and%20%272011-12-31%27) in the documentation on `datetime`.

It also automatically converts strings in the "right" format to `date`s:

```
where i.invoicedate between '20110101' and '20111231'
```

For almost all internationalization settings except 1, it also accepts hyphens for `date`s:

```
where i.invoicedate between '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-31'
```

I have a personal preference for the hyphens both for readability and ISO 8601 compliance.  Others prefer not using the hyphens because that is the SQL Server standard.  This really is a personal preference.

You can also use `convert()` if you really want to be specific:

```
where i.invoicedate between convert(date, '2011-01-01', 120) and convert(date, '2011-12-31', 120)
```

In your context, you only seem to need dates.  However, you are also suggesting that `invoicedate` is really `datetime`.  Then you should be careful about the time component. **My recommendation is to avoid `between` on date/time values.**

So, I suspect that you really intend:

```
where i.invoicedate >= '2011-01-01') and 
      i.invoicedate < '2012-01-01'
```

This will include all invoices sent on 2011-12-31 -- and this works for both `date` and `datetime` value.